# How to set SharePoint 2013 list field "only group" instead of "People and Group"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How to set "**Only Group**" picker in sharepoint 2013 list, instead of "**People and Group**"

Comment: I think SharePoint is not providing this in OOTB. Workaround of this is, create one dropdown and fill it with all the groups from the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint **is not providing this in OOTB**. But you can do the workaround for this.

You can create **one dropdown control** for that and fill it with SharePoint group names. Fetching group names from the site using below code.

**C# code:**

```
using (SPSite topLevelSite = new SPSite(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForumSharepointInstanceUrl"]))
{
using (SPWeb rootWeb = topLevelSite.OpenWeb())
{
foreach (SPGroup group in rootWeb.Groups)
{
//go do something clever...
}
}
}
```

Reference: this [link](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2007/09/spwebgroups-vs-spwebsitegroups.html)

**JavaScript code:**

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection ';

function retrieveAllUsersAllGroups() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    clientContext.load(collGroup);
    clientContext.load(collGroup, 'Include(Users)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var userInfo = '';

    var groupEnumerator = collGroup.getEnumerator();
    while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
        alert(oGroup.get_title());

    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with the out of the box columns provided by SharePoint 2013. One idea is that you can create a list an maintain the names of the groups there and have a lookup column created to that list.